# Best way to iterate/stream a Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark job which reads in a parquet file with about 150.000.000 key/value entries.

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
    conf.setAppName("Job");
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    SQLContext sql = new SQLContext(jsc);
    DataFrame df = sql.read().parquet(path);
```

My objective is to write key/value pairs to HBase but I get a heap memory issues and I suspect this is not the best way to do it. I would like to push the computation to cluster but I cannot figure out how to skip the collect part. Right now my code looks like this:

```
HBaseClient client = HbaseWrapper.initClient();
   df.collectAsList().stream().forEach(row -> {
            try {
                HbaseWrapper.putRows(client, row);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
   jsc.stop();
```

And I tried to collect as a List first without streaming and then write that down but that also takes forever.

Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting OOM error because collectAsList sends all the data to the driver.

To solve you can use foreachPartitions, so you'll stream to Hbase in parallel.

```
    df.toJavaRDD().foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<Row>>() {

        @Override
        public void call(Iterator<Row> t) throws Exception {
            try {
                HBaseClient client = HbaseWrapper.initClient();
                while(t.hasNext()){
                    Row row = t.next();
                    HbaseWrapper.putRows(client, row);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```